# Multiple Null one-to-many relationship with EF and MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create multiple One-to-Many and Many-to-Many relationships from one entity to multiple other entities.

The entity is a Call that can be related to a Lead or a Client or an Opportunity, but where do I create the relationship, in the Call entity:

```
public class Call 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Lead_Id? { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Lead_Id")]
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }    

    public int Client_Id? { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client_Id")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }    

    public int Opportunity_Id? { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Opportunity_Id")]
    public virtual Opportunity Opportunity { get; set; }    
}
```

And in the database table I create a column for each relationship?

Or do I create an external table used for Many-To-Many relationships but I use in this case in a One-To-Many relationship because I will only use one relationship for each call?

Comment: Are you using DB-first or code-first?

Comment: What is the **concrete** problem? Why would you use many-to-many? How wouldn't you implemente FKs in the DB instead of by using columns for that? Please, get clear what you try to do, what  your problem is, and rewrite the question.

Comment: @MatteoSganzetta Hi thanks, I create the database and then I create the model manually.

Comment: @JotaBe Hi thanks. I think it's a best practice question, adding columns in the table full of null values or adding a relationship table for each one.

Comment: So, given you want to use an existing DB with POCO classes (I guessed it from the code you posted), I assume you choosed to use Code First targeting an existing DB, as explained in this tutorial (this option is available starting from Entity Framework 6.1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx